# Cypress: cy.origin() requires the first argument to be a different domain than top. (For AAD authentification)

Tags: authentication, automation, cypress

For access to the desired page I have to passed the AAD authentication. I prepared the test as follows:

```
describe('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const username = Cypress.env("aad_username");
        const password = Cypress.env("aad_password");
      
        // Assuming `cy.loginToAAD` is a custom command that handles AAD login
        cy.loginToAAD(`${Cypress.env("baseUrl")}intranet/#/demande-inscription/rechercher`, username, password);

        //console.log(Cypress.env("baseUrl"));
      
        // Visit the URL directly without passing an empty object
        cy.visit(`${Cypress.env("baseUrl")}intranet/#/demande-inscription/rechercher`);
 
      })
    it('passes', () => {
        cy.get('#someElement').should('be.visible')

    })
})
```

## In the support file

```
function loginViaAAD(url, username, password) {
    cy.visit(url);
      
    // Login to your AAD tenant.
    cy.origin(
      "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      {
        args: {
          username,
          password
        }
      },
      ({ username,password }) => {
        cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {
          log: false
        })
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click().then(($password) => {
            cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, {
              log: false
            })
            cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
          })
      }
    )
    // Ensure Microsoft has redirected us back to the sample app with our logged in user.
    cy.url().should("equal", url)
    cy.get("#welcome-div").should(
      "contain",
      `Welcome ${Cypress.env("aad_username")}!`
    )
}

Cypress.Commands.add("loginToAAD", (url, username, password) => {
    cy.session(
        `${username}`,
        () => {
            const log = Cypress.log({
                displayName: "Azure Active Directory Login",
                message: [` Authenticating | ${username}`],
                // @ts-ignore
                autoEnd: false
            })

        log.snapshot("before")

        loginViaAAD(url, username, password)

        log.snapshot("after")
        log.end()
    },
    {
    validate: () => {
        // this is a very basic form of session validation 
        cy.visit(url)
        cy.get("#welcome-div").should(
        "contain",
        `Welcome ${Cypress.env("aad_username")}!`)
        }
    }
)
})
```

Erroer message
In this case after entering the desired URL firstly the user navigate to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/ page but after running the test case the test is failed and this error is displayed

cy.origin() requires the first argument to be a different domain than top. You passed https://login.microsoftonline.com/ to the origin command, while top is at https://login.microsoftonline.com.
Either the intended page was not visited prior to running the cy.origin block or the cy.origin block may not be needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is the `cy.visit()` in `loginViaAAD(url, username, password)`. It is the same as the origin, therefore it should be inside the `cy.origin()`

```js
function loginViaAAD(url, username, password) {
  // Login to your AAD tenant.
  cy.origin("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", {
    args: {username, password}
  }, ({ username,password }) => {
    cy.visit(url);
    cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {log: false})
    ...
```

`Cypress.env("baseUrl")` is also confusing because `baseUrl` is reserved for the origin of your app, but you use it for the url of the authentication endpoint.

You you change the name to something else like `aadUrl`.